# Wordpress Custom Featured image size?

Tags: wordpress

I have gone through each of the solutions I've found on here, and still cannot get my 'featured' image to show it's proper size, something continually is forcing it to the wp default 150x110 px.

I have gone into wp/settings/media and changed the thumbnail size... no change
I have gone into the gallery/ featured image and turned off all other sizes except for original... no change
I have gone into my functions.php file and changed the size that is supposedly being called..

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'homepage-thumb' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 420, 110 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 420, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited  height)
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb',420, 110, true ); //(cropped)
}
```

In my index file I have ...

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(420,110) );echo '</a>';} ?>
```

and still nothing..

When I inspect the element in firebug I see this:

```
<img class="attachment-420x110 wp-post-image" width="150" height="110" title="t-test2" alt="t-test2" src="http://pixelneer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/t-test2-150x110.png">
```

SO it is still getting the defualt thunbnail size from somewhere else, and I am at a loss.

I am using starkers, and the URL is [pixelneer](http://pixelneer.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call up the thumbnail, use the `image_size` name that you defined earlier. So for example instead of:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(420,110) );
```

Use:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'home-page-thumb' );
```

Comment: Thanks All. GhostToast, that's precisely what I was missing. I new it was something, minor (but HUGE) that I was overlooking.

Comment: Glad we could help. Sorry if this is out of line but would you mind choosing my answer as correct? Or upvoting it or however it works? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress generates thumbnails only at the time of uploading of the image. Later changes in thumbnail sizes do not automatically apply to existing images.

Try re-uploading your image, or use a plugin like the [Ajax Thumbnail rebuilder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of the image by name when you call it, otherwise it will default to thumbnail size - like this:

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumb' ); 
echo '</a>';} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your functions.php and look for this code

```
add_image_size( 'properties', 280, 200, TRUE );
```

280 is the width and 200 is the height in pixel.

This should solve your problem