# WordPress get_the_post_thumbnail - get the custom size image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set the featured image/ thumbnail to 600x530 in my functions.php:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(600, 530, true); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions (cropped)
}
```

But I can't retrieve that size via:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(600, 530), array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
```

The image I always get is **169x300** or the **large un-cropped original size**. But I want **600x530**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This explain it [Here](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/):

You can specify additional custom sizes! Here’s the code:

**functions.php**

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'single-post-thumbnail', 400, 9999 ); // Permalink thumbnail size
```

`home.php` or `index.php`, depending on your theme structure (in the loop)

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

`single.php` (in the loop):

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
```

Comment: im not going to retrieve the image via `the_post_thumbnail` bcos im using foreach to loop the result of `$pages = get_children($args, $output_type);`.

Comment: Kindly check that question. It related to your issue. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/115607. Hope it will work.

Comment: I think this is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500928/wordpress-custom-featured-image-size

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer:

[Wordpress Custom Featured image size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500928/wordpress-custom-featured-image-size)

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'homepage-thumb' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 420, 110 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb',420, 110, true ); //(cropped)
}
```

instead of:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(420,110) );
```

Use:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'homepage-thumb' );
```

Answer (score 0):

solution 1 : with `css` and custom `class name`

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'custom-class'));

# .custom-class{...}
```

solution 2 : adding custom size by `add_image_size()`

```
remove_filter('wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null');
add_image_size('single-post-thumbnail', 310, 155);
$thumbUri = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '')[0];
$gethumb = array('class' => 'custom-class','src' => '' . $thumbUri . '');
the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail', $gethumb);
```